# ipython notebook can import a pyd module but the python interpreter can't

Tags: python, pyd

I downloaded the cvxopt package and tried to run some of the examples from the documentation here

http://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html

Everything runs fine when I execute the code from ipython notebook.

However, when I try to run the interpreter I get the following :

import cvxopt:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cvxopt__init__.py", line 32, in 
    import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The command import cvxopt runs fine in ipython notebook. The module which can't be downloaded (cvxopt.base) is a .pyd file and is on the system path.

I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), run it on the .pyd, figure out which DLL it needs, and put the DLL where it belongs.

Comment: I did that and there were several DDLs missing. However, I can't find EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL anywhere

Comment: Looks like it was removed by the Windows 8.1 upgrade.

Comment: Any suggestions what to do about it? I find strange though that everything works fine from ipython notebook (no DLLs are required)